# Basic d3: Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Having trouble with a simple bar chart here, can't find the problem.

See this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/nn3yex69/

Notice two main problems:

1) The number of bars is not matching the number of elements in `dataset`.

2) The widths of the largest `rect`s extend to the full size of the `svg` despite the desired `padding` in `xScale`.

Would really appreciate any help here, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You are selecting all `rect` elements in the SVG. You already have one `rect` element: the background! Try changing line 36 to `svg.selectAll("rect.bar")`.

2) There's padding on the left and the right, so on line 17 use `.range([padding,w - (2*padding)]);`

Comment: would love to, seems like SO has a minimum timer, will do in a few minutes

Comment: Can you elaborate on (1) ? The goal is to change the selector to not include the `rect` which is just the background color. So why does the selector `rect.bar` work even though I don't have a `bar` class defined? (I notice that `rect.anything` works)

Comment: You want an empty selection, so that all data are bound to entering elements rather than updating (existing) elements. The longer answer is to understand D3 selections, start here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Answer (score 2):

You were appending a 'rect' and so on the selectAll('rect'), the first element from the dataset was being overridden by the attributes of the first appended 'rect'.

Removing the following will do the trick:

```
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "#ccc")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn3yex69/1/

I would create a div and style with css to be the containing div to hold your bars.